# CSS change the style vertical responsive menu

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation-6

How to change the style, if the menu switch to vertical?!?! [Responsive Menu](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/responsive-navigation.html#responsive-menu)

```
<ul class="vertical medium-horizontal menu">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried for example:

```
.vertical li{background-color: #000000;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the change in the corresponding @media query.

/*From the site you linked*/

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {

```
li {background-color: #000000;}
```

}